# How to connect to outlook.office365.com with POP3 by using OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, pop3

Currently we have a Spring Integration application using a mail inbound channel adapter for receiving and processing application emails. It connects to Outlook 365 using POP3 protocol using basic authentication with a user/password. Since Basic Authentication is being discontinued by Microsoft later this year we are required to migrate the authentication to OAUTH2 (Modern Authentication) token based access. In this regard my question is as follows:

```
    <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter  id="pop3Adater"
          store-uri="pop3s://user:password@pop3serverhost/Inbox"
          java-mail-properties=""
     />
```

The POP3 store-uri is

```
    pop3s://user:password@pop3serverhost/Inbox
```

How should the store-uri be modified to use oauth access token for autehtication? (We will only have an AZURE Base64 encoded access token)

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.